# How to write code to be executed BEFORE any method in an assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

There is an event [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.domainunload.aspx) which allows to clean up static resources which are independent of any particular instance of class and even of any particular class.
I consider it as the code which is executed AFTER any code in my current assembly (Am I right by the way?).

But is there a way to write a piece of code (for the current assembly) which is to be executed BEFORE any other code in the current assembly (class library)? Or should I look for a more tricky way to initialize some resources before any code started execution?

I know about static constructors, but the order of their calls is not well defined. In other words, there is no guarantee that a particular static constructor will be executed before other static constructors of other classes.

There is also an [`AppDomain.AssemblyLoad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload.aspx).  I am not sure this is the thing I am looking for. This event occurs when OTHER assemblies are loaded, not the current.

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad occurs when that particular assembly is loaded.

Comment: @Dejo but the assembly itself cannot find out when it is loaded.

Comment: >> AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad occurs when that particular assembly is loaded

Well, how can I write the code to be compiled in CURRENT assembly but executed in this event BEFORE this current is loaeded? Is it possible? Or should I write this code to be compiled to other dependent assembly?

Comment: It's not immediate, but you can, apart from the first assembly that is loaded. I do it as explained below

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it this way.
I define an `IAssembyInitializer` interface with just the method `void Initialize()`.
In every assembly for which I want to execute some code just after it is loaded, I define a class implementing this interface.
The I define an attribute to specify the classes in the assembly that implements this interface (otherwise you could find them out by Reflection, but I preferred it this way):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AssemblyInitializerAttribute : Attribute
{
    AssemblyInitializerAttribute ()
    {
    }
    AssemblyInitializerAttribute (string typeName)
    {
        TypeName = typeName;
    }
    public string TypeName;
}
```

The attribute is set in the AssemblyInfo in this way:

```
[assembly: AssemblyInitializerAttribute ("MyNamespace.AnAssemblyInitializer")]
```

Finally, in the main assembly of the application I register to the AssemblyLoad event a method that executes all the initializations:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += new AssemblyLoadEventHandler(NewAssemblyLoaded);

        static void NewAssemblyLoaded(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
        {
            Assembly anAssembly = args.LoadedAssembly;
            AssemblyInitializerAttribute[] initializers = (AssemblyInitializerAttribute[])anAssembly .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyInitializerAttribute), false);
            foreach (AssemblyInitializerAttribute anInit in initializers)
            {
                Type initType = anInit.TypeName != null ? anAssembly.GetType(anInit.TypeName) : null;
                if (initType != null && initType.GetInterface("IAssemblyInitializer") != null)
                {
                    IAssemblyInitializer anInitializer = (IAssemblyInitializer)Activator.CreateInstance(initType);
                    anInitializer.Initialize();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use instances of `Lazy<T>` held in static fields to control static initialization order yourself. The code body of those `Lazy<T>` initializer objects can reference other `Lazy<T>` instances which automatically orchestrates a DAG of initialization. You cannot have cycles, obviously.

With C++/CLI you can indeed have code executed when the assembly loads (module initializers). You probably don't want to go that route.

With C# this is not possible. Static ctors and lazy initialization patterns are the best you get.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to scan the code and find those places that require the initialization to be completed.

Then kickoff the initialization just before it is required when the initialization hasn't run yet.

In .NET you simply don't know when an assembly will be loaded so there is no guarrantee that the initialization will start in time for all scenarios.

An alternative would be for the client of the assembly to explicitly initiate the initialization by calling a method. (That will load the assembly too if it hasn't been loaded yet)

The AssemblyLoad event could be used like that in the client to detect the loading of a specific assembly but that will make the initialization dependent on the client implementation whereas the first solution keeps this responsibility in scope of the assembly itself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no control about how your class library is used, you could write static constructors for every public/protected class in the library and call the initialization code from every one of them. Obviously, the initialization code has to keep track of the first invocation (via a static field) so that it runs only once.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with [Module Initializers](http://einaregilsson.com/module-initializers-in-csharp/).  They're not directly supported in C#, but if you're not averse to using [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) to post process your assembly, you can use them.